# Dafny- Using a method to change a inside of a predicate

Tags: oop, formal-verification, dafny

I've written a class in Dafny that has the form

```
class Question{

    var a: int;
    var b: seq<int>;

    predicate isValid(something: Type) { .... }

    method X(something : Type) returns (b : int)
   {
       //utilises b to calculate a value for a 
       .....
   }

   predicate Second(something: Type) { a == X(something) }

   //"something" is the same for all predicates and functions
}
```

I know that I can't call the method in  the Second() predicate, but I want to assert that the integer "a" should be equivalent to some integer when given a variable "something", calculated with the method defined in the class. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to do anything with a method from inside a predicate. At best, if you have a strong specification for the method (eg using a logical formula to characterize what value X computes) you could refer to that specification in the predicate. You might get more helpful responses if you made the example more concrete.

Comment: Hey James, thanks for answering my question(again). Specifically, this question is part of my ongoing effort to prove what I can about Dijkstra's SSSP algorithm, like in my other questions. The code can be found at https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/plFong . I am talking specifically about the "Path" class, where I have an integer variable that represents the length of a path. The method getL(G: Graph) calculates the length of a given path and should be calculated using getL(G: Graph), but I don't know how to set its value using the method in such a way that I can then use that value in a predicate.

Comment: Also, sorry about the null-type warnings. I'm using an older version of Dafny.

Comment: There's no way to require a value to have been set by a particular method. What you need to do instead is express `getL` as a function instead. I will expand on this in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, there is no direct way for a method to influence any logical entity (such as a predicate). Instead, you need to characterize what you care about in a function, which you can then use to talk about the value.

Let me illustrate with the example code you mentioned in your comment. Consider the method `w` in the `Graph` class. This method has no side effect, and its return value will be useful in further specifications. We can replace it by a function `Weight` as follows.

```
function Weight(u: int, v: int): int
reads this, this.edges, this.vertices
requires this.isValid() && this.hasEdge(u,v)
requires u < d.Length && v< d.Length
{
  var f : Edge? :| f in edges && f !=null && f.source == u && f.dest == v;
  f.weight
}
```

In this case it was relatively straightforward: the bodies are essentially identical.

Here's another example where it's more complex. Consider the `getL` method in the `Path` class. Again, this method is side-effect free, so let's replace it with a function.

```
function Length(G: Graph?): int
reads ...
requires ...
{
    Sum(0, |pv| - 1, i /* ... */ => G.Weight(pv[i].id, pv[i+1].id))
}
```

We use `G.Weight` and a function `Sum` whose type looks (roughly) like this

```
function Sum(lo: int, hi: int, f: int -> int): int
decreases hi - lo
{
  if lo >= hi then 0
  else f(lo) + Sum(lo + 1, hi, f)
}
```

It sums the values of `f` over the range `[lo, hi)`.

Actually, we need a more powerful version of `Sum` that allows `f` to have a precondition and also to read the heap. Here's its type (the same body works).

```
function Sum(lo: int, hi: int, f: int ~> int): int
requires forall i | lo <= i < hi :: f.requires(i)
decreases hi - lo
reads set i, o | lo <= i < hi && o in f.reads(i) :: o
```

Notice that `->` became `~>`, and we added `requires` and `reads` clauses.

Back in `Length`, we also need to fill in some missing `reads` and `requires` annotations. Here is the full definition.

```
function Length(G: Graph): int
reads G, G.vertices, G.d , G.edges
reads this, this.pv
requires G != null && G.isValid() && this.isValid(G)
{
    Sum(0, |pv| - 1, i reads this, this.pv, G, G.edges, G.vertices, G.d
                       requires 0 <= i < |pv| - 1 && G.isValid() && this.isValid(G) =>
                       G.Weight(pv[i].id, pv[i+1].id))
}
```

This computes the same value as `getL`, and it can be used in specifications.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks James, but I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what is being done here beyond changing the methods to functions, specifically at this point : `function Length(G: Graph?): int
reads ...
requires ...
{
    Sum(0, |pv| - 1, i /* ... */ => G.Weight(pv[i].id, pv[i+1].id))
}` . At the point where we provide the 3rd argument to the "Sum" function, what exactly does the " i => G.Weight(...)" mean? The sum function specifies that the 3rd argument should be a function that takes an int and returns an int, but G.Weight() takes 2 ints and returns an int.

Comment: `i => ...` is an anonymous function (also known as a "lambda") that takes a single argument `i` and returns `G.Weight(pv[i].id, pv[i+1].id))`. The part that I have left out is the `reads` and `requires` clauses for the lambda. I'll add them to my answer just in case you need them.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it perfectly! I was getting a reads clause error and I was trying to fix it by adding the reads clauses to the "Length" function itself. I didn't know that you could do specifications for a function inside the definition for another function.

Comment: Glad it helps. You can read more about lambdas in section 22.9 of the Dafny Reference. https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Docs/DafnyRef/out/DafnyRef.pdf